# Pass assets image path as dynamic inline style background-image url (Nuxt.js)

Tags: css, vue.js, webpack, assets, nuxt.js

I'm working on a Nuxt.js app and I want to set the background image of an element dynamically with images from the assets folder, this is what I did:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div
      v-for="(image, imageID) in images"
      :key="imageID"
      :style="bgImg(image)"
    />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      images: [
        '~assets/img/image1.jpg',
        '~assets/img/image2.jpg',
        '~assets/img/image3.jpg',
        '~assets/img/image4.jpg'
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    bgImg(img) {
      return `background-image: url(${img})`
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**Expected behavior**

The div is rendered with dynamic background images

**Actual behavior**

The background image is not rendered. If I put the static assets path into css file, it is rendered

How do I have to pass the path for this to be rendered correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Nuxt Webpack build process messes with *some* urls

So the issue is that paths in templates and CSS are processed by Webpack's file-loader when the project is built. For example `~assets/` gets rewritten at build time to be the actual path after webpack's processing is done.

However, since you're specifying the path strings as part of the vue.js data, Webpack doesn't touch them.

To resolve this create a "static" directory at the root of your project (assuming you don't have one already). Inside of that, create an "images" directory. Webpack will copy everything thing inside `static` to the `dist` folder when the build is run.

The path to these images to use inside your component is then `/images/filename.ext`

Comment: that is what i was trying to avoid, i'm currently handling the dinamic images that way, but the docs i have been reading say that this is not optimal.

Comment: Not optimal for what reason?

Comment: "If we move our dog images into the public folder (or the static folder in Nuxt), “it works”. But it is not optimal and I really would not recommend that workaround. The difference between the two folders assets and public/static, and the reason why the first attempt failed, is Webpack.

Content in the public or static folder, is directly mapped to the root of your web applications (usually /) and not processed by Webpack. No optimizations, added content hashes and so on."

Extracted from https://blog.lichter.io/posts/how-to-load-dynamic-images-in-vue-and-nuxt-with-ea/

Comment: Well, that's a bit perspective based. Are you letting Webpack resize or recompress your images? Are the images changing frequently so they SHOULD NOT be cached? If you're not doing those things, you actually get a huge benefit from the `cache-control` policy that webpack assigns to `static` content.